# what is the root of this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots, factorial

Let

$f_n(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x+i)-n!=(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)-n!$

$n$ is a positive integer.
What are the roots of the polynomial for a given $n$ except $0$?
Or determine the real part of the roots or even determine the maximum real part of the roots except $0$.

Thanks!

Comment: Um.... your function of "$x$" is independent of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed this.

Comment: I think this only has 1 real root at x=0, since any x greater than 0 would result in the product being greater than n!. Can’t say anything about the complex roots.

Comment: Are you expecting a closed form to describe the general n-th root? or are you looking for some values (how many)? Do you want imaginary roots as well?

Comment: I am more interested in the real part of the roots or even the range of the real part of each root.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler Don't we have a root at $x=-n-1$ in case $n$ is even?

Comment: @EdG You are correct, zeroes exist at the even values of $i$ and each is  $x=(-1)(i)-1$, for the odd values of $i, x=0$. This is all about real roots. Have not investigated the complex roots.

Comment: Yes we do. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

There are always $n$ complex solutions to degree $n$ polynomial, thanks to the fundamental theorem of algebra. I will only provide real solutions here. Note that:

For $x>0$, the value is always greater than zero.

For $x<-n-1$, the absolute value is always greater than zero.

For $0>x>-n-1$, the value can't be zero.

Since $x=0$ is one real root and $x=-n-1$ is the other real root if $n$ is even, the polynomial has one or two real roots.

Attached are cases when $n=3$ and when $n=4$:
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to determine the real part of these roots?

Comment: I think you mean $0 > x > -n-1$.

Comment: Yes, Can we be more specific? like to find the maximum real part of the roots.